# How to prevent Barcode Scanner Device automatically writing on edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio, barcode-scanner

I have Barcode Scanner Device which communicates via Bluetooth.  I have KeyEvent for making Toast when it scans, but fragment also contains EditText, and when I scan, it automatically writes on EditText, whereas I want to make toast instead

> How can I do that? Any ideas?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    String str_array="";
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        for(char ch:arrayList){
            str_array+=String.valueOf(ch);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"BarCode : "+str_array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        arrayList.clear();
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Its not clear with question, i am assuming EditText is taking focus by default . you can set layout property as well to avoid this.easiest solution will be in `Manifest` add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your `activity` .

Comment: The device sounds like it is in HUD mode which makes it act as a keyboard, change the mode to SPP (Serial Port Profile). onKeyUp wont be used anymore so you have to change your logic

Comment: @tyczj actually you may be right. After you said I have opened instruction paper and there is written two operations mode: basic and spp. Now I am trying to understand SPP mode.  Thanks